# Ubuntu will not install alongside Windows - No Option

Tags: ubiquity

I have a HP dv6 stock laptop. I had 12.04 installed and all went well with Wubi and I loved it.

I updated to 13.04, but it created WiFi issues and I was advised to complete a fresh install which I tried, but now, Ubuntu wont install alongside Windows. It gives me the option to install inside windows. The boot helper keeps giving me errors, such as installation files can not be found and NoneType object does not have attribute fields.

I have re downloaded the ISO, and tried again but the install alongside is still not there. Any advice?

Comment: Did you try to boot your system with the CD inserted and selecting in the BIOS to boot from the CD?

Comment: No I did use that method with the usb to no avail.

Comment: Did the pc boot directly to windows?

Comment: No, it ran from the usb, and it gave me the the option to install inside windows, or replace. When I hit install inside windows it would restart to windows.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the installation of Ubuntu you should make sure that you shutdown Windows **completely**. If the installation still don't show options, you should verify and repair any error that your partitions should have. For that, boot up Windows and run:

```
chkdsk /f C:
```

for each partition you have, example if you have 3 partitions called: C, D and H, you should:

```
chkdsk /f C:
chkdsk /f D:
chkdsk /f H:
```

This process could take a while, or require you to restart the machine.